# How does Blender decide random physics events?

Tags: physics

I placed a cube over a plane and made both of them rigid bodies, and gave the cube a box shape under the rigid body options (the cube is active and the plane is passive). The bottom of the cube is parallel to the plane. However, when the cube falls, it doesn't bounce straight up, but in the way you would expect a die to bounce. It seems to me that Blender is adding some sort of random variable to the collision, but it falls exactly the same way every time. I'd like to make the cube fall in several different ways. Is the "random variable" for the collision seeded in some way, and can I change the seed?

Comment: Sims use random numbers, but they aren't really random, using the same seed will always give the same sequence of numbers. Most sims have a seed value but it looks like the seed used for rigid body is based on object data, you can move a vertex slightly and get a different sim.